# Extjs : How I can create contextmenu in menu

Tags: events, extjs, menu, contextmenu

If we can create contextmenu in menu (use contextmenu event)?

I use next code:

```
for (i=0, len = response.result.data.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    itemData = response.result.data[i];
    item = menu.addMenuItem({
        id   : itemData.id,
        text : itemData.name
    });
    item.addEvents('contextmenu');
    item.on({
        click       : this.onClickConfig,
        contextmenu : this.onContextMenuConfig,
        scope       : this
    })
}

onClickConfig : function(menuItem, e) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Click','you clicked on me');
},

onContextMenuConfig : function(e) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Click right','you clicked right on me');
    e.preventDefault();
},
```

It's OK for the left click, but it does not work for rigth click

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to find contextmenu as a valid event for anything in the Ext.Menu package.

You can possibly override the Ext.menu.item object and add your own context menu handler.